# Remote JMX monitoring Jconsole JDK 1.7.0_91

Tags: java, monitoring, jmx

I need to monitor my VCenter Server application(It's a Java application) using JMX.

I have seen many posts on this and followed but still I'm not able to get it to work.

The VCenter is running on a VM on our internal network.

Had made these changes in the wrapper.conf file

```
wrapper.java.additional.22="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
wrapper.java.additional.23="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1100"
wrapper.java.additional.24="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
wrapper.java.additional.25="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
wrapper.java.additional.26="-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=hostname where vcenter runs"
#wrapper.java.additional.27="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1100"
```

I'm able to connect Jconsole to 1100 port locally. As soon as I start the service, I see that the port listens properly

```
PS U:\> netstat -an | findstr 1100
   TCP    0.0.0.0:1100           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
   TCP    [::]:1100              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

As soon as I try to connect it from my laptop, it displays this

```
PS U:\> netstat -an | findstr 1100
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1100           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    "ipofvcenterserver":1100      11.248.18.xx:51988     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::]:1100              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

[Update]
I noticed that if I add Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1100 , and I connect using jconsole, the established connections shows as below. But 11.248.18.xxx is not the IP address of the remote client (my laptop)

```
PS U:\> netstat -an | Findstr 1100
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1100           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    ipofrmiserver:1100      11.248.18.xxx:56728     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    ipofrmiserver:1100      11.248.18.xxx:56729     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::]:1100              [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

I see that there is some connection established, but still, jconsole complains that it is not able to connect

Troubleshooting steps were done:

1) Turned off firewall on the vcenter server machine to keep things simple
2) telnet to 1100 works from my laptop
3) tried copying the jmxremote_optional.jar to VMWARE_JAVA_HOME\lib which is C:\Program Files\VMware\vCenter Server\jre\lib according to this post https://meteatamel.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/jmx-rmi-vs-jmxmp/
4) Able to ping hostname of server where Vcenter runs
5) tried without this wrapper.java.additional.27="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1100"
6) Tried tcpdump, but couldn't make any sense since I'm not a network guy.

Updating log image
[image]

Updating config images

[image]

Can't imagine anything else. If anyone else has some clue, please advice.

Comment: Where is JMX code? What is problematic part? your script? JMX code? JConsole? I am confused.

Comment: There is no java code involved. I use Jconsole application from my laptop to connect to a remote java process which is my Vcenter application running on the remote machine.I provide the IP address of the remote machine and the port number in Jconsole remote process section. The configuration shown is the Vcenter application running on Tomcat on the remote machine.

Comment: Ok, so what is the response you are getting on JConsole?

Comment: Connection failed:retry? The connection to "11.168.32.xxx":1100 did not succeed. Would you like to try again

Comment: Try JConsole with debug trace and post the stack. https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/troubleshooting_connection_problems_in_jconsole

Comment: In the blog link you had provided, the link with the steps gives 404 not found error. http://blogs.sun.com/roller/page/jmxetc?entry=tracing_jmx_what_s_going . I ran this command jconsole -J-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib\logging.properties and there is a windows opening up which shows usage. Could you please let me know how to get the traces or point to some documentation which has? Thx

Comment: Whatever window opening up will print exception message if it is due to protocol or authentication etc., could you update question with your JConsole screenshot?

Comment: uploaded image.

Comment: Interestingly message saying connecting to host 127.0.0.1 (not sure why), can you update question with JConsole screen (and URL format) you are using? You are sure that there are no firewalls on 1100 right? What port Tomcat JMX (on destination running)?

Comment: yes, Firewall turned off, Uploaded image for your reference.

Comment: That URL in "remote process" is not correct (that might work if remote process is on same machine) I use service-jmx URL to connection to remote machine. Right below that text box, there is an example how URL should be, did you try that?

Comment: This is an example service:jmx:rmi://IP:port

Comment: I had tried it earlier once I think .service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://11.168.32.xx:1100/jmxrmi   Getting the same error failed to connect: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect . And moreover the established doesn't appear in the listening port if used to connect that way

Comment: Remove jndi/rmi

Comment: java.net.MalformedURLException: URL path must begin with /jndi/ or /stub/ or /ior/: when I used service:jmx:rmi://11.168.32.xx:1100

Comment: I use service URL in my java program (with http remoting for JBoss monitoring), it works fine for for me, not sure what is wrong on your end. Are you sure Tomcat RMI listening on 1100?

Comment: When I stop the VMWare service, then  netstat -a -n -o| Findstr 1100 doesnt display anything. So I think it runs something related to the service, but not sure if it is RMI. BTW, in the error connection refused to host should be my laptop ip instead of 127.0.0.1 if it is proper? Maybe the property of hostname wasnt identified properly by the server. Anyways, thanks a lot for trying to help me out :)

Comment: The issue is with the Vcenter application somewhere it seems so, I'm able to connect remotely to a standalone Apache tomcat application.

Comment: I think this is more of vCentre vm firewall issue (or) protocol issue. Any way good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally was able to get it working for one service. Hope people don't have to spend 3 days tearing hairs to figure this out.....

The file in question was in C:\Program Files\VMware\vCenter Server\vdcs\vdcserver\conf\server.xml

```
<Listener accessFile="${catalina.base}/conf/jmxremote.access" authenticate="false" bind="11.168.32.xx" className="com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener" passwordFile="${catalina.base}/conf/jmxremote.password" port="${base.jmx.port}" useSSL="false"/>
```

The bind value above seems to override the wrapper.conf properties, it was earlier 127.0.0.1. And changed the authentication to false seemed to do the trick temporarily. Would need to work to make it more secure now.

Comment: I think you can have authenticate true and supply username/pwd in JConsole, where do you configure authentication credentials on vCentre, I have no idea.